# Need assistance with program, having trouble with FileInputStream only reading one line of a text file. [HomeworkHelp]

Tags: java, xml, fileinputstream

So I have to do a program that basically tests that an XML text document is nested properly. I figured this is actually one of our easier assignments this semester, but what I'm having trouble with is reading the text file line by line. I have implemented code for FileInputStream that our professor provided us with, and from there I've been having problems with it. Basically, my code validates the first line of the text file, then ends. I must be doing something wrong with my FileInputStream, I'm just not quite sure what. Any help is appreciated.

```
// The XMLParser class prompts the user for a filename and reads an XML 
// document from the given text file. The program then reports that either the 
// document is valid based on XML rules or there was an error at a certain 
// line of input due to a violation of rules of XML tags.

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class XMLParser {        
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    //creates a scanner to read the users input of the file name
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //creates an integer that will be incremented for every line read
    //to help with error reporting
    int currentLine = 1;

    //creates a stack that elements will be pushed on to
    //and popped off of, strings to represent opening and closing
    //tags of an xml document, and a string to represent the root 
    //tag (the first tag used)
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    String open = "<";
    String close = "</";
    String root = "";


    //prompts the user to input a file name then reads from
    // the file the user entered
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the file to be read: ");
    String fileName = input.next();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(fis);
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(inStream);
    String data = stdin.readLine();

    String nextDataValue;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(data);

    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        nextDataValue = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();

        //if the xml document begins with anything other than
        //a root tag, an error is reported and the program ends
        if (root.equals("") && !nextDataValue.startsWith(open)) {
            System.out.println("PARSE ERROR Line 1, your XML document does not start with an opening tag and is therefore invalid\nProgram terminating normally...");
            break;
        }

        //pushes an "opening tag" onto the stack
        else if (nextDataValue.startsWith(open) && !nextDataValue.startsWith(close)) {
            stack.push(nextDataValue);

            //checks if there is already a root value, and if there
            //is not it adds one
            if (root.equals("")) {
                root = root + nextDataValue;
            }

        }

        //if a closing tag is found, this pops the stack and compares
        //the closing tag with an opening tag to see if it is properly
        //nested, if not an error statement is printed and the program
        //ends
        if (nextDataValue.startsWith(close)) {
            String compareClose = nextDataValue;
            String compareOpen = stack.pop();
            compareClose = compareClose.replace("/", "");
            if (!compareClose.equals(compareOpen)) {
                System.out.println("PARSE ERROR Line " + currentLine + ", you have improperly nested the tag: " + compareOpen);
                break;
            }
            //if the closing tag is the root tag and there is nothing
            //after this closing tag, the document is valid.
            if (compareOpen.equals(root) && !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                System.out.println("Input XML document is valid");
            }
        }       


        currentLine++;
    }




}
}
```

tl;dr: Why is my FileInputStream going through one line of code and then just stopping. Did I do something wrong in my while loop or is it something else that I'm unaware of?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `String data = stdin.readLine();` this should be in the loop. else every time it will read just one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies within this line: `String data = stdin.readLine();`. The way you are doing it will instruct the program to only read one line, validate it, and exit. What you need to do is to a while loop similar to this:

```
String data = "";
while ( (data = stdin.readLine()) != null)
{
    //Read and validate the line you are reading
}
```

This will allow you to load a new line of text per iteration. Once the the `EOF` will be encountered, the `stdin.readLine()` should return null, thus breaking your loop and making your program execution stop.

Answer (score 1):

Like they said, you only read one line from the BufferedReader

And you also need to notice the empty element such as

```
<emptyElement />

String open = "<";
String close = "</";
String close1 = "/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You read a line only once. Before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call readLine repeatedly, e.g. in a loop, to read more than one line.